# Is there a way to create custom objects for TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tinymce

I've been trying to come up with a way to create custom objects for use inside TinyMCE and unfortunately have been largely unsuccessful through reading their documentation and googling. It would seem like in order for the editor to handle existing objects such as images and divs, there must be a way to do this, but everything I've come up with so far is really unappealing to my sense of how this functionality should be set up. The primary example that I'm trying to accomplish is to allow the user to insert bootstrap carousels but this is something I have yet to see done. One method I've toyed with trying is to just create a custom element and then have TinyMCE swap it out when it's time to save changes, but again this really feels like a last resort type of route.

I've read that CKEditor has a `Widget` class which sounds kind of like what I'm looking for (as far as I understand it at least), but I'm hesitant to switch because TinyMCE has patched the missing native feature to resize images in webkit based browsers. The site I'm creating will be primarily for photography so manipulating images with ease is a big selling point, even though CKEditors developer tools are far more appealing.

Does anyone with slightly more TinyMCE experience than I be able to point me in a worthwhile direction? Whenever I search keywords like 'Widget' in google I end up with results pertaining to TinyMCE as a widget for other applications. Thanks.